# Angular 2 ngOnInit Called Twice With Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I ran into a strange error in Angular 2. I have two similar components with similar templates and similar services. Here is the basics of how they work:

Component:

```
theData: any;

constructor(private _theService: TheService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._theService.getData()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.theData = data;
        });
}
```

Service:

```
private _url = "http://url.net/api/Data";

constructor(private _http: Http) {
}

getData() {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

this returns an array of objects, like:

```
[
    {name: "Name 1"},
    {name: "Name 2"}
]
```

and the Template displays them like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of theData">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

Then you can click into an item where you are taken to a page that follows the same strategy as above, except the service/api only returns a single object and the template does not use *ngFor because there is only one item to show.

So it looks like:

```
theItem = {name: "Name 1"} // what the service returns

<div>{{ theItem.name }}</div>
```

Everything works great when displaying all items, but when I click into the individual items, OnInit is called twice and I get an error in platform-browser.umd.js which is really an error in the template because it says the it can't read the property `name` of `undefined` (which is theItem).

I solved this problem by changing the template for individual items to:

```
<div>{{ theItem?.name }}</div>
```

At first I thought the problem was that the template was rendering before the data had loaded from the service, so adding `?` fixed it. But shouldn't the template be loading AFTER ngOnInit has finished? My question is, why did adding the `?` fix this problem, even though I don't need it in the first template when loading all items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, the `get` is asynchronous, it does in fact begin to render the template before the data is loaded.  It will fire off the service call and won't wait, it will continue processing.  Adding the `?` allows it to be `undefined` and then render appropriately once the data is loaded.

Comment: Ok, so the only reason it works in the first scenario is because the service is returning the data fast enough, and the template hasn't been rendered yet?

Comment: or the `*ngFor` is handling it being undefined, whereas directly referencing the object doesn't. I'm honestly not sure, I've never really dug into that scenario

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if it was *ngFor handling it as well, and I think that's the case. I'll report back if I find anything else on that. Thank you!

Comment: Got the same problem word for word. Another way to solve it is using `*ngIf="theItem"`in the template root node. This avoids using `?` on every binding. My previous templates worked fine because they were using it already. Also, note that I encountered this problem because my component is using route parameters, which are retrieved from `ActivatedRoute` through an `Observable`, hence why the "delay" I guess.